# How to use datalist in react-native

Tags: react-native, datalist

How to use `datalist` in react-native.I want to use `datalist` in react native with fetch api .
I use laravel for back end so I want to fetch data in react native `datalist`

Comment: There are many types of list in React Native. ScrollView, FlatList, SectionList... You should check which data list do you want first.

Comment: i need text input where i can write and  Users will see a drop-down list of pre-defined options as they input data

Answer (score 1):

Use `react-native-autocomplete-input`

> $ npm install --save react-native-autocomplete-input

```
render() {
  const { query } = this.state;
  const data = filterData(query);
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      data={data}
      value={query}
      onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ query: text })}
      flatListProps={{
        keyExtractor: (_, idx) => idx,
        renderItem: ({ item }) => <Text>{item}</Text>,
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

[react-native-autocomplete-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-autocomplete-input)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Flatlist` in react-native to show the dynamic data like

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://reactnative.dev/movies.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json.movies))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
      {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Text>{item.title}, {item.releaseYear}</Text>
          )}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: i need that thing in react native  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp